# Как включить подтверждения при перетаскивании файлов и папок (drag and drop) в Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Желательно без сторонних утилит. Ну или хотя бы вообще его выключить. Спасибо.

Comment: В связи с чем такая потребность? Может просто отобрать все права кроме чтения в проблемных папках?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Проблема заключается в случайном перетаскивании при неудачном двойном клике. Особенно актуально при просмотре директории в виде таблицы, когда расстояние между строками минимально. В некоторых программах, например в WinSCP, есть такая опция.

Comment: [When people ask to disable drag and drop, they often are trying to disable accidental drag and drop](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090410-00/?p=18583)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Disable COPY drag and drop in Windows Explorer in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/922645/761205)

Comment: @Grundy О, я видел это решение. Удивился его кривости и не стал применять т.к. подумал что это какой то неопытный пользователь его придумал. А оказывается это в Microsoft придумали...

Comment: @hipster MS, как правило, только к третьей версии продукта придумывают правильное решение.... Впрочем, почти все монополисты таковы, полмесяца назад ЖУТКО разочаровался в Intel

Comment: Вполне толковое решение. Грамотно продуманное API которое вполне работает после 20 лет.